# Issue while trying to read Table - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I believe that this is a really basic problem but i am starting my coding at PHP so i really can't do it all alone:

I've been for 2 days trying to solve a strange problem. I am using XAMPP for my database and its tables with the objective of creating a login and register system.

This is my user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `playware`.`users` (
`user_id` INT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`name` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`surname` VARCHAR( 25 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR( 35 ) NOT NULL ,
`telephone` VARCHAR( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
UNIQUE (`email`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

The register .php file is working (it's adding the user to the table correctly) but when i try to make login i just can't.

So I've made this on my login.php file just to test if it gets the row:

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
{
    header("Location: index_home.php");
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$upass = $_POST["password"];
$sql="SELECT email FROM users";
$res=$conn->query($sql);
if($res->num_rows>0)
{
    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc());
    {
        if($row["email"]==$email)
        {
            echo"Writting email: ".$row["email"]." - done writting.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

All time i try to do this results on a white screen, nothing more, when it's supposed to appear the user email. Someone knows how to fix this?

================================**UPDATE**==================================
The error was:

```
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc());
{
    //Stuff here ...
}
```

It can't take the ";" there because it cancels the outputting. So the fix is:

```
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
(...)
```

As I expected, it was a basic error ... Thank you for people that supported me.

Comment: Turn on your error_reporting first

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: first thing `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` will not work how you think it does and it will always be true. `isset` returns a boolean value so this should be `if(empty($_SESSION['user']))`.

Comment: Do you have that `$conn` object instantiated somewhere?

Comment: I am using a newer version than 5.5 ...
How do I check error logs if it's not showing nothing?
Thank you for the tip mic, i've changed it!

Comment: The error logs are on your web server.

Comment: Jay, i've checked the error.log at XAMPP directory, wich is the file that saves all error logs, within PHP errors. It didn't appeared nothing related with this problem. Oh and $conn var is instanciated at connect.php file and it's working fine! Also, i have already 1 row registered ... I really can't understand why it's not working, maybe i have to use functions instead of arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
```

You cannot check if a variable is set and not equal to blank in this way. Instead you should do this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!="")
```

You have another error here, which stops the script from outputting anything:

```
while($row=$res->fetch_assoc());
---------remove the -----------^
```

Since that is valid syntax you may not have seen anything in error reporting.

---

You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

In addition make sure you're using [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and/or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: why not just do an empty check?

Comment: You could do an empty check @mic - there are many ways to skin a cat.